# calculate SUM of multiple Case When

Tags: sql

My data has 3 groups of variables `(set1_a,b,c,) (set2_x,y), (set3_n)` as below. For each group, if at least 1 variable has `value>90` then I count as 1.

Then, I SUM the count.

My code below works fine. However, I would like to put all in 1 select statement.
Can you please help?

```
Create TABLE have  (
    id varchar(225),
    set1_a varchar(225),
    set1_b varchar(225),    
    set1_c varchar(225),
    set2_x varchar(225),
    set2_y varchar(225),    
    set3_n varchar(225)   
);
Insert into have (id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n) values (1,1,3,200,1,1,5);
Insert into have (id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n) values (2,1,3,200,200,1,5);
Insert into have (id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n) values (3,1,3,200,200,1,500);
Insert into have (id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n) values (4,1,3,1,1,1,500);
select * from have;

SELECT id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n,N1,N2, count1+count2+count3 as total_count FROM
(
select id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n, 
case
  when (set1_a >90 or set1_b>90 or set1_c>90) then 1 else 0
end as count1,
case
  when (set2_x >90 or set2_y>90) then 1 else 0 
end as count2
case
  when (set3_n >90) then 1 else 0 
end as count3
from have
) 
--WHERE N1+N2>=2
;
```

Comment: What do you want to calculate, strings (varchar)?

Comment: You already have one select statement. Do you mean you're trying to get rid of the subquery?

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in `varchar` columns? That is a **really**, really bad idea. Don't do that

Answer (score 0):

This works. Also, ideally the data type should be `int` and not `varchar` since you are comparing with `int`.

```sql
SELECT id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n,
(case 
  when greatest(
    cast(set1_a as int), 
    cast(set1_b as int),
    cast(set1_c as int)
  )>90 then 1 else 0 end) +
(case 
  when greatest(
     cast(set2_x as int),
     cast(set2_y as int)
   )>90 then 1 else 0 end) +
(case
  when cast(set3_n as int) > 90 
  then 1 else 0 end 
) as total_count
from have
```

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0d93982434ea783eb791872ca32b4586) on postgres 11 for the same. But it's all standard sql.

Comment: Thank you for helping, AnkurSaxena!